# Load multiple scripts in Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am new to angular 6. I just start learning angular 6. While creating a project i am stuck into error.

I am simply adding external scripts into my component and getting error

Here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'src/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
import 'src/assets/js/countdowntime.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comingsoon',
  templateUrl: './comingsoon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comingsoon.component.css']
})

export class ComingsoonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log($) // here is am getting output
  } 

}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at Object..
/src/assets/js/countdowntime.js (countdowntime.js:92)
```

Comment: Are you thinking of building a Countdown Timer, like [this](http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/index-2.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Update your code

Add jQuery to your index.html or angular.json file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comingsoon',
  templateUrl: './comingsoon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comingsoon.component.css']
})
export class ComingsoonComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
   // load countdown 
     var c = document.createElement("script");
     c.type = "text/javascript";
     c.src = "src/assets/js/countdowntime.js";
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c);
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(jQuery) // here is am getting output
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add jquery as a package and reference it in your component code, so it can get picked up by Webpack:

```
$ npm add jquery
```

Then inside your TypeScript code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

...

export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log($);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**
Use Jquery types

Need to add types for jquery version.
you can find jquery types here

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery
```

As typescript is strongly typed
For all items which we use in a component should have types

**Solution 2 :**

create a variable $ and assign its type to any

A workaround if you're not able to find type for the current jquery version which is

```
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comingsoon',
  templateUrl: './comingsoon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comingsoon.component.css']
})
```

inside your component life cycle check the value of the dollar, you will find jquery properties and method. Your error will be resolved

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log($) 
}
```